# Nashorn with open-jdk 11.0.1 throws java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, java-11, nashorn, openjdk-11

I have a Java Application that uses open-jdk 11.0.1 “2018-10-16” to build/run the application.

While opening the application, it tries to use the system's proxy configuration.
For some PAC scripts it's throwing **java.lang.StackOverflowError**. The PAC script belongs to our user who isn't willing to share it.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.LocalVariableTypesCalculator.enterBinaryNode(LocalVariableTypesCalculator.java:445)
at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.BinaryNode.accept(BinaryNode.java:332)
at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.LocalVariableTypesCalculator.enterJoinPredecessorExpression(LocalVariableTypesCalculator.java:778)
at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.JoinPredecessorExpression.accept(JoinPredecessorExpression.java:114)
at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.LocalVariableTypesCalculator.visitExpression(LocalVariableTypesCalculator.java:604)
at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.LocalVariableTypesCalculator.enterBinaryNode(LocalVariableTypesCalculator.java:448)
at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.BinaryNode.accept(BinaryNode.java:332)
at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.LocalVariableTypesCalculator.enterJoinPredecessorExpression(LocalVariableTypesCalculator.java:778)
at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.JoinPredecessorExpression.accept(JoinPredecessorExpression.java:114)
at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.LocalVariableTypesCalculator.visitExpression(LocalVariableTypesCalculator.java:604)
at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.LocalVariableTypesCalculator.enterBinaryNode(LocalVariableTypesCalculator.java:448)
at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.BinaryNode.accept(BinaryNode.java:332)
at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.LocalVariableTypesCalculator.enterJoinPredecessorExpression(LocalVariableTypesCalculator.java:778)
at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.JoinPredecessorExpression.accept(JoinPredecessorExpression.java:114)
at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.LocalVariableTypesCalculator.visitExpression(LocalVariableTypesCalculator.java:604)
at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.LocalVariableTypesCalculator.enterBinaryNode(LocalVariableTypesCalculator.java:448)
at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.BinaryNode.accept(BinaryNode.java:332)
at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.LocalVariableTypesCalculator.enterJoinPredecessorExpression(LocalVariableTypesCalculator.java:778)
at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.JoinPredecessorExpression.accept(JoinPredecessorExpression.java:114)
```

Increasing the stack size fixed the issue, but is it possible to determine what kind of a PAC script would cause a recursive parsing like that?
We use the proxy vole library and it seems the nashorn engine is parsing the JS expression.

I wasn't able to reproduce by simply using a large PAC script. I have created a PAC file with size of 2-10 MB and wasn't able to recreate the issue.

I am providing the StackOverflowError trace, which may help determine the nature of the JS expression which cause this.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72647713/standalone-nashorn-with-java-11-throws-java-lang-stackoverflowerror-upon-eval